# Linked Data Signature using Javascript Verification Error

Tags: cryptography, json-ld, ed25519

```
import { Ed25519VerificationKey2020 } from "@digitalbazaar/ed25519-verification-key-2020";
import { Ed25519Signature2020 } from "@digitalbazaar/ed25519-signature-2020";
import jsonSigs from "jsonld-signatures";
import jsonld from "jsonld";
import { CryptoLD } from "crypto-ld";
(async () => {
  const cryptoLd = new CryptoLD();
  cryptoLd.use(Ed25519VerificationKey2020);
  cryptoLd.use(Ed25519Signature2020);
  const edKeyPair = await cryptoLd.generate({
    type: "Ed25519VerificationKey2020",
    controller: "https://w3id.org/security/v2",
    id: "did:asd:tanjin#z6MknpatYMfHz3di8zdbHcWZfBHz4VDNfvmDD27Uf5eqZ6Aq",
    controller: "https://example.com/i/carol",
  });

  const keypair = edKeyPair.export({
    publicKey: true,
    privateKeyBase58: true,
    controller: true,
  });

  const { AuthenticationProofPurpose } = jsonSigs.purposes;

  const purpose = new AuthenticationProofPurpose({
    challenge: "ABC",
    domain: "http://localhost:3000",
  });
  const doc = {
    "@context": ["https://schema.org"],
    "@type": "https://schema.org/Person",
    name: "Tanjin Alam",
    url: "https://vishwas.netlify.app/",
    image:
      "https://asdf.com",
    description:
      "Tanjin Alam is a software developer. He is trying to learning cryptography",
    birthdate: "1996-11-16",
    jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
  };
  const signed_doc = await jsonSigs.sign(doc, {
    documentLoader: jsonld.documentLoaders.node(),
    suite: new Ed25519Signature2020({
      key: edKeyPair,
    }),
    purpose,
  });
  console.log("signed_doc", signed_doc);
  const purposesss = new AuthenticationProofPurpose({
    edKeyPair,
    challenge: "ABC",
    domain: "http://localhost:3000",
  });
  const verficiaiton = await jsonSigs.verify(signed_doc, {
    purpose: purposesss,
    suite: new Ed25519Signature2020({
        key: edKeyPair,
    }),
  });
  console.log("verficiaiton", verficiaiton);
})();
```

from the first console i am getting following output

```
    signed_doc {
  '@context': [
    'https://schema.org',
    'https://w3id.org/security/suites/ed25519-2020/v1'
  ],
  '@type': 'https://schema.org/Person',
  name: 'Tanjin Alam',
  url: 'https://vishwas.netlify.app/',
  image: 'https://asdf.com',
  description: 'Tanjin Alam is a software developer. He is trying to learning cryptography',
  birthdate: '1996-11-16',
  jobTitle: 'Software Engineer',
  proof: {
    type: 'Ed25519Signature2020',
    created: '2023-06-28T17:35:54Z',
    verificationMethod: 'did:asd:tanjin#z6MknpatYMfHz3di8zdbHcWZfBHz4VDNfvmDD27Uf5eqZ6Aq',
    proofPurpose: 'authentication',
    challenge: 'ABC',
    domain: 'http://localhost:3000',
    proofValue: 'z3r8zfvUDiJVmvg3SvpmdZyGj1bujXkvhXiEc8XEbfyGXAa7W42q5aeHPMZeuWv2jf6UWapp9he6rnmHxdwibx4bA'
  }
}
```

which seems okay but when i am trying to verify the proof i am having following error

```
verficiaiton {
  verified: false,
  results: [
    {
      proof: [Object],
      verified: false,
      verificationMethod: undefined,
      error: [JsonLdError]
    }
  ],
  error: VerificationError: Verification error(s).
      at Object.verify (/Users/piash/Desktop/Blockchain-Research/did-backend/node_modules/jsonld-signatures/lib/jsonld-signatures.js:180:22)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async file:///Users/piash/Desktop/Blockchain-Research/did-backend/index.js:54:24 {
    errors: [ [JsonLdError] ]
  }
}
```